# ADO.NET cache-like behavior when filling a datatable ein .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, .net-4.5

I have a code with a loop that uses a stored procedure to fill a DataTable. The rowset generated by the stored procedure is **always** different, since it's a counter that is updated on each call.

Notice that each call to the stored procedure is done with exactly the same parameters.

I've tested it on SQL Manager Studio and it worked fine. In .NET 3.5 it also worked fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
   {
       SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", cn);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text));

       string AlwaysDifferentCounter = "";
       MyDatatable.Clear();
       MyDatatable = cmd.Fill();


       AlwaysDifferentCounter = MyDatatable.Rows[0]["Counter"].ToString();
       //AlwaysDifferentCounter value always is the same 

   }
```

After a migration to the Framework 4.5 it isn't working, because it is filling the datatable with the same rowset.

I've tried to get the counter from an output parameter and it works fine, but in the rowset it is still out of date.

```
       AlwaysDifferentCounter = MyDatatable.Parameters["@Counter"].Value.ToString();
       //AlwaysDifferentCounter now it has a different value on each call
```

**Why is this happening? Is there any cache behavior in Framework 4.5?**

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable to return a single value?  string counter = (string)SQLcmd2.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @Blam Because I'm returning a lot more data, this is just an example.